# Tracking a server side redirect in Google Analytics in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I am using `Google Analytics` in my project and I am getting redirect request on one of my page. I want to track that request, tt is on server side.

How can I track request on server side in ASP.NET MVC C#?